# React-JS- get array index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello guys I'm a beginner in react.

I am developing in react-js and with noSQL database (Firebase).

I have a collection and within that collection I have 3 documents each with an automatically generated id.

I am creating a function for adding comments and I wanted this function to run as follows.

As soon as you click on the "comment" button for a specific post, be redirected to a modal with that specific post and have the input for adding text (comment).

I already have the modal created and a map () returning all documents from the same collection. however, this map returns all documents and not just the specific document that I click on the "comment" button. could someone help me, please?

example : How can I render only the index 0 of this array in my modal?

My problem is: I'm not getting a way to return just a specific document from that collection. my map returns all documents to me at once.

```
States:
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {    
      Posts: [],
      idDoc: [],
      openComent: false,
    }


 abrirComent() {
    if (!this.state.openComent) {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.isInPageModalComent, false);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.isInPageModalComent, false);
    }
      this.setState( prevState => ({
        openComent: !prevState.openComent
      }));         
    }
  // adding (node) at DOM;
  isInPageModalComent(e) {
    if(this.node) {
        const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.node);
        if(this.node.contains(e.target)) {
            return domNode;            
      }             
    }     
        this.abrirComent();       
  }
```

code jsx:

```
  {this.state.openComent && (        
    <div>
      <div className="overlay">
        <div ref={node => {this.node = node}} className="Modal-Comentario" style={{overflowY: 'scroll'}}>
          {this.state.Posts.map((itens,index) => {
            return (
            <div>
              <div className="viewPost-content" key={index}>
                {/* get background-color post */}
                <div className="viewPost-box" style={{backgroundColor: itens.colorBg} } >   
                    <p> <Moment to={itens.createdAt.toDate().toString()} /> </p> 
                    <button id="PostDelete" onClick={this.deletePost}> <ion-icon name="ellipsis-horizontal-sharp"></ion-icon> </button>                
                    <h2 className="text-post"> {itens.texto} </h2>                  
                    <div class="viewPost-icons">
                      <div style={{marginRight: '-5px', backgroundColor:'transparent'}}> <button id="bt-Posts" onClick={this.abrirComent}><ion-icon                 name="chatbox"></ion-icon></button></div>
                       <div> Comment: <input type="text" /> </div>                                             
                    </div>
                </div>                
              </div>
            </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>        
  )}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: don't worked . i'm still with same problem.

Comment: Providing an example we can run (Stackblitz, etc) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of map and give each post a unique id to be used in the callback function.